# Installing ROS for an NXT

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am interested in using ROS to program an NXT. I am very new to ROS and Linux, but not to robotics and I am interested in learning ROS. When I add the following line to terminal:

*sudo apt-get install ros-electric-nxtall*

I get the text below in terminal. Is the electric version the proper version that I need to use? How can I fix this problem? Thank you for your help!

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-diamondback-nxtall : Depends: ros-diamondback-nxt-apps (= 0.1.1-s1315535128~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.3-s1315532575~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-joystick-drivers (= 1.4.2-s1315007432~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-ros (= 1.4.10-s1314988837~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-visualization (= 1.4.1-s1315011843~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-perception-pcl (= 0.10.0-s1315007603~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-rx (= 1.4.2-s1315010621~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-diagnostics-monitors (= 1.4.0-s1315018722~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-image-common (= 1.4.1-s1315006405~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-nxt-robots (= 0.1.2-s1315534008~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-ros-comm (= 1.4.8-s1314988916~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-visualization-common (= 1.4.2-s1315010803~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-driver-common (= 1.2.3-s1315006323~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-executive-smach (= 1.0.3-s1320177847~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-common-msgs (= 1.4.0-s1315005773~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-nxt (= 0.1.1-s1315020497~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-robot-model (= 1.4.0-s1315008455~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-geometry (= 1.4.2-s1315006035~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-executive-smach-visualization (= 1.0.1-s1321804721~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-laser-pipeline (= 1.2.0-s1315009845~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-common (= 1.4.3-s1315005864~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-diagnostics (= 1.4.0-s1315006219~natty) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-diamondback-navigation (= 1.4.2-s1315423226~natty) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54844/installing-ros-for-an-nxt/) by [FIRSTlover](https://answers.ros.org/users/4173/firstlover/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is better to upgrade your ubuntu installation to the latest LTS version and install ROS fuerte or groovy.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0